# stdlib.h doesn't have declaration for putenv

Tags: c, linux, c99

I've tried compiling the following code with `gcc 4.7.3` and `clang 3.2.1` on Ubuntu 13.04 (64-bit):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main() {
    putenv("SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED=1");

    return 0;
}
```

I expected `putenv` to be declared in the `stdlib.h` header, but I get the following warning:

```
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:6:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘putenv’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
```

Why is the declaration for this function missing in my header?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to define certain macros. Look at `man 3 putenv`:

```
NAME
  putenv - change or add an environment variable

SYNOPSIS
   #include <stdlib.h>

   int putenv(char *string);

Feature Test Macro Requirements for glibc (see feature_test_macros(7)):

   putenv(): _SVID_SOURCE || _XOPEN_SOURCE
```

Try defining either `_SVID_SOURCE` or `_XOPEN_SOURCE` before including `stdlib.h`, like so:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
#include <stdlib.h>
```

Or when compiling (with `-D`), like:

```
gcc -o output file.c -D_XOPEN_SOURCE
```